# Options for reporting date ranges in a compact way

Tags: british-english, dates

I am exceeding the word limit in an abstract. What are my options for limiting words in the following sentence?

> The study included patients with X diagnosis between **1 January 2009
> and 30 September 2017**
>
> The study included patients with X diagnosis between **January 2009
> and September 2017**

Comment: ...  includes X patients diagnosed in Jan 2009 through Sept 2017.

Comment: As @Jim says, but consider diagnosed Jan 2009-Sept2017. It depends partly on whether you are fitting to space or to a computer-calculated word count.

Comment: @Jim's suggestion won't work in British English. Please edit the tags in your question to indicate which English (American, Australian, British, Indian, Irish...) you're asking about.

Comment: The study included patients diagnosed with X between 1/1/09 and 30/9/17